# Как сделать свой голос для голосового ассистента?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Пишу голосового ассистента на python, хочу чтобы ассистент отвечал пользователю **моим** голосом. *Как такое можно такое реализовать?*

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Простите, но если вам нужен готовый код - гуглите. Если при дальнейшей разработке столкнётесть с конкретной проблемой - задавайте вопрос здесь.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно воспрозводить аудио-файлы через pygame.

Например:

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

...
...
...

def goanswer(answ): # функция воспроизведения голоса
    answ += ".wav"
    pygame.mixer.music.load(answ) # загрузка файла
    pygame.mixer.music.play() # воспроизведение файла

if txt=="exit": # если сообщение пользователя = выйти
    goanswer("ok") # воспроизведение "ок"
    exit() # выход
```

Остаётся только записать отрывки голоса, которые будут воспроизводится.

Comment: а можно не записывать отдельные фразы, а например, чтобы можно было ввести любое слово(в консоль например), и воспроизводилось это слово моим голосом? Но я не знаю какое слово будет введено.

Comment: @BEYandBLADE вряд-ли, только если записать каждую буквы и её воспроизводить, но это будет звучать крайне упорото.